# Prove that $(\frac{\pi}{3})^{\frac{3}{\pi}}+(\frac{3}{\pi})<2$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, alternative-proof, pi

Prove that :

$$\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^{\frac{3}{\pi}}+\frac{3}{\pi}<2$$

Straightforward proof :

Since the function $f(x)=(x)^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing on$\left[1,\frac{\pi}{3}\right]$

We get :

$$f\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^{\frac{3}{\pi}}+\frac{3}{\pi}<f(1)=2$$

So we get an almost integer easily .

### My questions :

Have you an alternative proof ?

Can we find other almost integer with this way?

Thanks a lot for all your contributions .

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjustOB to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) for exponents $\in[0,1]$
$$\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^{\frac{3}{\pi}}+\frac{3}{\pi}=
\left(1+\frac{\pi-3}{3}\right)^{\frac{3}{\pi}}+\frac{3}{\pi} \leq
1+\frac{\pi-3}{3}\cdot \frac{3}{\pi}+\frac{3}{\pi}=\\
1+1-\frac{3}{\pi}+\frac{3}{\pi}=2$$

Comment: ... with the equality being strict because $\pi\ne 3$ (cf. conditions for strictness in Bernoulli's inequality)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen it's the very fist pattern that came to my mind ... but yes, it should be strict.

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks a lot !